# Convert a Windows bat file to Linux sh shell script

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, converters, sh

I am trying to parse and merge a large number of csv files containing Ordnance Survey address data.  The OS provides a batch file, but I want to be able to run it on the Linux server because the files are huge.

I've tried to convert from the bat file to ssh using this [very hand guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html).  However I am struggling with calling the procedure.  Is anyone able to check what is wrong?

The original script (I've truncated it a bit here)

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('dir *.csv /b/s') DO (CALL :process "%%A" "%%~NA")
@rem -- merge the individual record identifier files
copy *_10_Records.csv Master_10_Records.out
copy *_11_Records.csv Master_11_Records.out
copy *_15_Records.csv Master_15_Records.out
copy *_21_Records.csv Master_21_Records.out
del *_Records.csv

@rem -- add header records to the individual record identifier files
copy Record_10_HEADER_Header.csv+Master_10_Records.out ID10_Header_Records.csv
copy Record_11_STREET_Header.csv+Master_11_Records.out ID11_Street_Records.csv
copy Record_15_STREETDESCRIPTOR_Header.csv+Master_15_Records.out ID15_StreetDesc_Records.csv
copy Record_21_BLPU_Header.csv+Master_21_Records.out ID21_BLPU_Records.csv
del *.out
pause
exit

@rem -- split the source csv into individual files based on the record identifier
:process
SET tempvar1=%~1
SET tempvar2=%~2
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"10\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_10_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"11\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_11_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"15\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_15_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"21\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_21_Records.csv
GOTO :EOF
```

My (poor) attempt at translating it to shell script syntax:

```
FOR /F A IN ['dir *.csv /b/s'] DO (CALL :process "%%A" "%%~NA")
# merge the individual record identifier files
cp *_10_Records.csv Master_10_Records.out
cp *_11_Records.csv Master_11_Records.out
cp *_15_Records.csv Master_15_Records.out
cp *_21_Records.csv Master_21_Records.out
rm *_Records.csv

# add header records to the individual record identifier files
cp Record_10_HEADER_Header.csv+Master_10_Records.out ID10_Header_Records.csv
cp Record_11_STREET_Header.csv+Master_11_Records.out ID11_Street_Records.csv
cp Record_15_STREETDESCRIPTOR_Header.csv+Master_15_Records.out ID15_StreetDesc_Records.csv
cp Record_21_BLPU_Header.csv+Master_21_Records.out ID21_BLPU_Records.csv
rm *.out
sleep
exit

# split the source csv into individual files based on the record identifier
:process
export tempvar1=%~1
export tempvar2=%~2
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"10\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_10_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"11\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_11_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"15\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_15_Records.csv
gawk < %tempvar1% -F "," "{ if ($1 == \"21\") { print $0 } }" > %tempvar2%_21_Records.csv
GOTO :EOF
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!  I've learned a lot by Googling but I am still new to this.

Comment: Please indicate the line(s) you are having problems with.

Comment: Probably a lot of them by the looks of it...

Comment: vars are defined like `tempvar=xxxx` (no spaces around equal sign!), and then referenced with `"$tempvar"` (good habit to surround most var references with dbl-quotes). Recall that anything inside of single quotes will NOT have the variables expanded to their values. Good luck.

Comment: Also +1 for some attempt to solve your problem. (Compared to other questions, I don't know why others are voting to close). For awk inline scripts, it is best to quote them with single-quotes, otherwise the $1, $0, etc belong to the shell environment (not the awk environment).

Comment: there are dozens of examples of `for` loops to process file lists here on S.O. Search for `[bash] for`. Basically, if is `for f in *.csv; do process1 "$f"; process2 "$f" ; done`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try something like the following. (Note that I haven't actually tried it but I hope it helps you.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# split the source csv into individual files based on the record identifier
function process() {
  tempvar1="$1"
  tempvar2="$2"
  awk < "$tempvar1" -F "," '{ if ($1 == "10") { print $0 } }' > "$tempvar2"_10_Records.csv
  awk < "$tempvar1" -F "," '{ if ($1 == "11") { print $0 } }' > "$tempvar2"_11_Records.csv
  awk < "$tempvar1" -F "," '{ if ($1 == "15") { print $0 } }' > "$tempvar2"_15_Records.csv
  awk < "$tempvar1" -F "," '{ if ($1 == "21") { print $0 } }' > "$tempvar2"_21_Records.csv
}

for A in *.csv ; do
  process "$A" "${A%.*}"
done
# merge the individual record identifier files
cat *_10_Records.csv > Master_10_Records.out
cat *_11_Records.csv > Master_11_Records.out
cat *_15_Records.csv > Master_15_Records.out
cat *_21_Records.csv > Master_21_Records.out
rm *_Records.csv

# add header records to the individual record identifier files
cat Record_10_HEADER_Header.csv Master_10_Records.out > ID10_Header_Records.csv
cat Record_11_STREET_Header.csv Master_11_Records.out > ID11_Street_Records.csv
cat Record_15_STREETDESCRIPTOR_Header.csv Master_15_Records.out > ID15_StreetDesc_Records.csv
cat Record_21_BLPU_Header.csv Master_21_Records.out > ID21_BLPU_Records.csv
rm *.out
echo -n "Press ENTER to continue..."
read DUMMY
exit
```

What it does / differences:

- The sub-routine `process` has been moved before the for loop and converted to a bash function. (See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) There will be no quotation marks so the tilde expansions (`%~1`) can be simplified to just `"$1"`.
- The for loop simply picks up all files with extension csv. I think the `%%~NA` expands to the filename without extension in CMD. In bash `${A%.*}` will remove the extension. See [Bash Reference Manual - Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx.
- The DOS `copy` command does not only copy (like `cp`) but concatenate multiple files which is done using `cat` in the bash script. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240268.
- The pause command prints a prompt and waits for a key to be pressed. In bash you can do that with echo and waiting for ENTER to be pressed by waiting for the user to input a (empty) dummy line by pressing ENTER.